# Mismatch Between Aptitude's GUI Error/Warning Messages and Its Log Entries

Tags: debian, logs, aptitude

Backstory [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/757781/where-does-aptitude-log-its-warnings).

In order to replicate the problem stated in the title:

1. Induce an error condition by introducing a spurious line to the `sources.list` file
2. Invoke **Aptitude** thusly via the command line `aptitude --log-file=foo.log`

This causes the **Aptitude** GUI to appear with 5 error messages in a red box:

[image]

Expecting to see all five of said error messages in the newly created log file, I examine the contents of **foo.log**. I see only *two* error message present there, none of which is present in said GUI's red boxed display:

```
2023-09-30 13:18:21 [140,425,484,097,408] apt.cc:426 ERROR aptitude.apt.globals - Failed to load the apt cache; trying to open it without locking.
2023-09-30 13:18:21 [140,425,484,097,408] apt.cc:436 ERROR aptitude.apt.globals - Unable to load the apt cache at all; giving up.
```

One can see that the error messages as presented on the GUI screen are much more descriptive and helpful than those transcribed to the temporary log file.

**Is there any way to get Aptitude to log the *exact* errors/warnings it displays in the red box?**